# Visual Studio 2008 sql query syntax; drop the brackets

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to configure VS2008 so that it does NOT create SQL query strings with square brackets in my ASP .Net projects?  I'm using a MySQL DB which doesn't like the brackets.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's [an option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) in the latest version of the MySQL connector which might help:

> Sql Server Mode
>
> Allow SQL Server syntax. When set to
> true enables Connector/NET to support
> square brackets around symbols instead
> of backticks. This enables Visual
> Studio wizards that bracket symbols
> with [] to work with Connector/NET.
> This option incurs a performance hit,
> so should only be used if necessary.
> This option was added in version
> 6.3.1.

Comment: Works great! My connection string in web.config now looks like:     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="v1ConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=btlogv1;Sql Server Mode=True"
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>